# Dapper and user defined database types

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, dapper

Let's say I have a user defined data type in the database: 
`MySuperType` which as two bigint properties in it (Id + Code)

And I have a stored procedure which takes in those parameters:

```
@MySuperType, @Price, @dateModified, etc...
```

Now in my code, I am using Dapper like this:

```
using (var connecion = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
{
    result = connection.Execute("SP_name", 
                new {mySuperType, price, date}, 
                commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
}
```

But I keep getting an error

> Type Operand clash: Dapper is not able to map the user defined type: MySuperType from the parameters to the stored procedure.

Changing the stored procedure or replacing the user-defined type isn't an option

Does anyone have an idea what I can do to map the types and send the parameters (all of them) to the stored procedure?

Answer (score 1):

Tha names of parameters must correspond to parameters defined in procedure:

```
using (var connecion = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            result = connection.Execute("SP_name", 
                new {MySuperType = mySuperType, Price = price, dateModified = date}, 
                commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
        }
```

Dapper is case sensitive in mapping in 2 directions (as parameters and as results).

If you want to avoid specifying names of the parameters, make sure you have it exactly same in variables in c# and stored procedure.